# How to use bootstrap with notepad++?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, notepad++

I am using **Notepad++** for `html` and `CSS`. I recently learned that we can add `Bootstrap` to `html` for creating websites. I learned few topics from [codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/). 
My question is when we are giving link for `css` file in `html`, we also need to give link for `bootstrap` `css` file. What is the format of giving `<link href="________">` for bootstrap css file?

Comment: just give the path of the bootstrap css and js files in <head> and its done , u can do this in any editor , is there any specificity with nodepad++

Answer (score 3):

Notepad++ is just a text editor,  if you still using notepad++ for bootstrap codes you can use [this project](https://github.com/dotcodes/Boot-hint)  for autosuggestion of bootstrap codes including glyphicons and font awesome icons.
https://github.com/dotcodes/Boot-hint

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is just a combination of HTML, CSS and JS. You can use any editor you prefer like Notepad++. Here is an example of a basic bootstrap template:

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- your layout style -->
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <!-- Js in bottom so the DOM will laod Faster-->
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When you are in production stage you must include `bootstrap.css`, this CSS have set of predefined properties to your template.

Answer (score 0):

The format for the link to a bootstrap is the same as the format to css, although with a little difference.
This is how a bootstrap link is below. **Content** is the folder which contains your bootstrap files, **bootstrap.min.css** is the actual bootstrap file, **rel="stylesheet"** specifies the relationship between the current document and the linked document and **type="text/css"** specifies the nature and format of the linked document.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to start:

Step 1:

- Navigate to the website [Download Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) and click on Download BootStrap button.

Step 2:

- Create a folder in your local drive and save the bootstrap css files to the created folder.
  [Ex:C:\Projects\BootStrapFromNP]

Step 3:

- Now right click on any of the browser page and click on "save as". It will be saved in html format.

Step 4:

- Open with notepad++ and delete all text inside it.

Step 5:

- Replace with below text:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h3>Testing BootStrap Classes</h3>
  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Step 6:

- Alternatively you can replace the bootstrap cdn link withyour local downloaded css file path as

```html
<link href="bootstrap/"YourBootstrapVersionNumber"/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the link from Bootstrap CDN (Content Delivery Network) to Speed up the Web Page because many users have automatically downloaded (cached) Bootstrap from it's CDN while visiting other Bootstrap Web Sites. Also when requesting file from a CDN, It gives the files from the Closest server to the user. Then it also increases the Speed of the Web Page Content. Here are the codes to include bootstrap css & bootstrap javascript inside a web page.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```